# nunit3-console Invalid: .csproj File type is not supported

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I have a Windows Server 2019 that works as a build node for Jenkins. The Windows box does not have a GUI, there is only SSH access that drops into PowerShell Core. The box has been configured with Ansible and all software is installed using Chocolatey.

```
- name: Install multiple packages
  win_chocolatey:
    name:
      - 7zip
      - ghostscript
      - imagemagick
      - jfrog-cli
      - maven
      - mingw
      - nodejs
      - nuget.commandline
      - nunit-console-runner
      - nunit-extension-nunit-project-loader
      - openjdk11
      - openjdk8
      - powershell-core
      - visualstudio2017buildtools
      - zip
    state: present
```

This is the output of `nunit3-console.exe --list-extensions`:

```
PS C:\Users\ansible> nunit3-console.exe --list-extensions        
NUnit Console Runner 3.12.0 (.NET 2.0)
Copyright (c) 2021 Charlie Poole, Rob Prouse
Monday, March 15, 2021 10:02:26 AM

Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
   Runtime: .NET Framework CLR v4.0.30319.42000

Installed Extensions
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/NUnitV2Driver
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/IService
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/ITestEventListener
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/IDriverFactory
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/IProjectLoader
    Extension: NUnit.Engine.Services.ProjectLoaders.NUnitProjectLoader(.NET 2.0)
      Version: 3.6.0.0
      Path: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nunit-extension-nunit-project-loader\tools\nunit-project-loader.dll
      FileExtension: .nunit
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/IResultWriter
```

When running `nunit3-console`, I get an error **File type is not supported**:

```
jenkins@EC2AMAZ-90KNPC6 C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\FOO>"C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\nunit-console-runner\\tools\\nunit3-console.exe" FOO.csproj --config=Release --test=SpecFlow.GeneratedTests --result=CucumberTestResult.xml 
NUnit Console Runner 3.12.0 (.NET 2.0)
Copyright (c) 2021 Charlie Poole, Rob Prouse
Friday, March 12, 2021 10:16:35 AM

Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
   Runtime: .NET Framework CLR v4.0.30319.42000

Test Files
    FOO.csproj

Test Filters
    Test: SpecFlow.GeneratedTests

 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "HEAD^{commit}" # timeout=10

Errors, Failures and Warnings

1) Invalid : C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\FOO\FOO.csproj
File type is not supported

Test Run Summary
  Overall result: Failed
  Test Count: 0, Passed: 0, Failed: 0, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
  Start time: 2021-03-12 10:16:35Z
    End time: 2021-03-12 10:16:35Z
    Duration: 0.328 seconds

Results (nunit3) saved as CucumberTestResult.xml

ERROR: script returned exit code -4
```

Already tried:

Originally `nunit-extension-nunit-project-loader` was not installed.

Before installation:

```
PS C:\Users\ansible> nunit3-console.exe --list-extensions
NUnit Console Runner 3.10.0 (.NET 2.0)
Copyright (c) 2019 Charlie Poole, Rob Prouse
Monday, March 15, 2021 9:05:00 AM

Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000

Installed Extensions
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/NUnitV2Driver
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/IService
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/ITestEventListener
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/IDriverFactory
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/IProjectLoader
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/IResultWriter
```

After installation:

```
PS C:\Users\ansible> nunit3-console.exe --list-extensions        
NUnit Console Runner 3.12.0 (.NET 2.0)
Copyright (c) 2021 Charlie Poole, Rob Prouse
Monday, March 15, 2021 10:02:26 AM

Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
   Runtime: .NET Framework CLR v4.0.30319.42000

Installed Extensions
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/NUnitV2Driver
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/IService
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/ITestEventListener
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/IDriverFactory
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/IProjectLoader
    Extension: NUnit.Engine.Services.ProjectLoaders.NUnitProjectLoader(.NET 2.0)
      Version: 3.6.0.0
      Path: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nunit-extension-nunit-project-loader\tools\nunit-project-loader.dll
      FileExtension: .nunit
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/IResultWriter
```

Same error **File type is not supported** before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That loader loads nunit projects. You want the `VSProjectLoader`.

Install with

```
choco install nunit-extension-vs-project-loader
```

or add `nunit-extension-vs-project-loader` to the list of packages installed by the `win_chocolatey` Ansible module.

After installation:

```
PS C:\Users\ansible> nunit3-console.exe --list-extensions
NUnit Console Runner 3.12.0 (.NET 2.0)
Copyright (c) 2021 Charlie Poole, Rob Prouse
Monday, March 15, 2021 12:30:17 PM

Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
   Runtime: .NET Framework CLR v4.0.30319.42000

Installed Extensions
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/NUnitV2Driver
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/IService
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/ITestEventListener
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/IDriverFactory
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/IProjectLoader
    Extension: NUnit.Engine.Services.ProjectLoaders.NUnitProjectLoader(.NET 2.0)
      Version: 3.6.0.0
      Path: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nunit-extension-nunit-project-loader\tools\nunit-project-loader.dll
      FileExtension: .nunit
    Extension: NUnit.Engine.Services.ProjectLoaders.VisualStudioProjectLoader(.NET 2.0)
      Version: 3.8.0.0
      Path: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nunit-extension-vs-project-loader\tools\vs-project-loader.dll
      FileExtension: .sln .csproj .vbproj .vjsproj .vcproj .fsproj
  Extension Point: /NUnit/Engine/TypeExtensions/IResultWriter
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I can't find that in the Chocolatey Gallery: https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=VSProjectLoader
Do you happen to know the package name?

Comment: Might be this one? `choco install nunit-extension-vs-project-loader`

Comment: The build takes about 2.5 minutes, I'll have feedback soon.

Comment: Looks ok. I'll edit your post to make it more useful, upvote and accept.